# Android build failed app:dexDebug error

Tags: android, exception, build

If i just build my project, it says build successfull. But if i run my project it says build failed. This is what it says

```
> :app:preDexDebug
trouble processing "javax/xml/bind/Binder.class":
Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
when not building a core library.

>This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file
in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as
Eclipse). If you are sure you're not intentionally defining a
core class, then this is the most likely explanation of what's
going on.

>However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core
namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example,
from a non-Android virtual machine project. This will most
assuredly not work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the
compatibility of your app with future versions of the platform.
It is also often of questionable legality.

>If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only
appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine
distribution, as opposed to compiling an application -- then use
the "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.
If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact
building an application, then be forewarned that your application
will still fail to build or run, at some point. Please be
prepared for angry customers who find, for example, that your
application ceases to function once they upgrade their operating
system. You will be to blame for this problem.
If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a
core package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to
repackage that code. That is, move the classes in question into
your own package namespace. This means that they will never be in
conflict with core system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help
you in this endeavor. If you find that you cannot do this, then
that is an indication that the path you are on will ultimately
lad to pain, suffering, grief, and lamentation.

>1 error; aborting

>Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 7.485 secs
```

Please help. I have checked for duplication of jar files. I have only 1 copy of each jar file.

My build.gradle looks like this

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.user.chillum"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
compile files('libs/javax.ws.rs.jar')
compile files('libs/jersey-client.jar')
compile files('libs/android-ws-combine.jar')
}
```

Please help.

Comment: you are probably adding a duplicate library in your build.gradle file (if u are using android studio) or there may be a library there which contains that jar also.For example if you are adding support v4 in your  app and any other library has v4 already then this error may arise and you better use  exclude module: 'support-v4' with that library

Comment: Please post your build.gradle.That will help a lot in checking the error

Comment: like i told you i have checked for the duplicates. I get errors if i remove even one of the .jar files.

Comment: Please check the build.gradle now.

Comment: try commenting all the libs except appcompat and check by uncommenting them one by one so that we can check as to which lib is causing prob.

Comment: Same error. Did not help. The thing is, in all cases, if i just build project, it is successfull. But i get this error when i run it.

Comment: try commenting all libs except appcompat

Comment: Yeah i tried every combination. Not helping.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I had to update the versions of the libraries (now appcompat is in 22.1.1) and check if the jar was in the libs folder, remove the "compile" lines from the build.gradle file (app) if they were duplicated.
Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

you probably have deleted the folder libs.
And the
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
don't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Enable the multidex support.

```
 defaultConfig {
            ...
            minSdkVersion 14
            targetSdkVersion 21
            ...

            // Enabling multidex support.
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
```